# How do I automatically save what's in my TextArea upon closing the window?

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, static

I have a Java GUI program that simulates a simple text field(to be like sticky-notes). I want to be able to click the close button and it automatically saves it to a pre-defined text field in the directory.

But I am having trouble with static errors:

```
File: C:\Users\Adel\Code\Javas\popupText.java  [line: 538]
Error: non-static method open() cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Here is the main method of my program:

```
 public static void main(String args[])
  {
    popupText note = new popupText("Untitled-Notepad");
    note.setSize(600,600);
    note.setLocation(200,200);
    note.setVisible(true);

    WindowListener exitListener = new WindowAdapter() {

      @Override
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        int confirm = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Are You Sure to Close Application?", "Exit Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
        if (confirm == 0) {

          open();   //THIS CAUSES ERROR!!
          System.out.print("Yay I openeed");
          addToStatic();  //just added @ end
          System.exit(0);
        }
      }
    };
    text.append(guts);

    note.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE); 
    note.addWindowListener(exitListener);
```

The text area is  simple and looks like so, and if you like I can give the full code of that too(it's just a bit unformatted at the moment):

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`main` is `static`, but the `open` method is not.

You can only access `static` methods (and fields) from other `static` methods.

Without further code, I suggest you try something like `note.open()` instead (assuming `open` is a method of note)

Comment: SWEET! It worked! I only needed to add 'final' also. Thanks very Much!

Answer (score 4):

**-** `main` is a `static` method.

**-** A `static` method **canNot** access a `Non-static` **variable or method**.

**-** `open()` method seems to be a **Non-static** method. so it think you need to create an instance of the class where open() method is defined, then access it using the `.`(dot) operator.